# Filtering objects from a List

Tags: java, list, user-interface, javafx

now I have been stuck on this problem for some time now and was wondering if anyone could be of assistance. I have made a Java GUI (a module picker for final year University students) and I just can't get one bit to work.

Background: It should be easy to add new modules and courses, so I am trying to avoid hard coding. Now all I am trying to do is let the program import certain modules depending on course. It's very trivial and I can get it to work a dirty way, but no the way I want.

```
if(course.getCourseName() == "Computer Science") {
        select.setModules(courses[0].getModulesOnCourse());
    } else if(course.getCourseName() == "Software Engineering") {
        select.setModules(courses[1].getModulesOnCourse());
    }
```

Now that way works, but it is hard coding level 1000. They way I wanted it to work was either of these two:

```
courses.forEach(c -> {if(c.equals(course)){select.setModules(c.getModulesOnCourse())}});
```

OR

```
for(Course c : courses) {
        if(c.equals(course)) {select.setModules(c.getModulesOnCourse());}
    }
```

Now they both theoretically should work perfectly, but neither do. I'm just wondering if anyone can help me understand why and maybe offer a solution. For ease I will attach a gist of all files below.

[The gist](https://gist.github.com/MrDWilson/8f09e93a31566be795458d22f8077429)

Comment: Did you override `equals()` method of `Course`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `==` with objects such as `String`s is never a good idea. Always use `.equals`.

If you're using `.equals` with your own custom objects, make sure you override the `.equals` method and code it so that you can define your own conditions for what makes two courses equal. If you don't do this, the method will most likely always return false.

Comment: That worked amazingly thanks. I know about overriding equals methods but I didn't realise it was this necessary. I presumed the method already there would do the trick, but obviously not. Thank you. I now know for future reference as well!

Comment: Happy to help. Interestingly, it's mostly accurate to imagine that `Object`'s `equals` method is the same as `==`, so you should always override it if you think there's a chance it'll be used.